# Highlight for reputation notifications in top bar is too small

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

When I move my mouse over the little inbox icon, it gets highlighted pretty well:

[image: top bar 1]

Sure, it's half a pixel off-center, but it's pretty good.

But when I move my mouse over my reputation notification:

[image: top bar 2]

The grey is the wrong size!  It looks weird.  Not only is it not centered, it's too thin.

This happens in Firefox 39.0 and Chrome 41.0.2272.43.  It doesn't affect the mobile site.

Comment: Have you tried checking your achievements more often? :)

Comment: @CopperKettle so after changing the reps +7400 and still no issue? Could you please add the screenshot of the same, if possible.

Comment: @snailboat could you please tell what is the browser version

Comment: @HackerKarma - sorry, I didn't notice that aspect of the issue.

Comment: @CopperKettle no problem, give it a shot by editing reps. value in dev tools... I have added the screenshots in my answer for reference

Comment: [tag:status-not-worth-fixing-since-this-is-not-something-that-should-happen-under-normal-circumstances].

Comment: Fun fact: exact same bug, reported by a different user, got tons of downvotes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: It's tempting to think it's just because it's, y'know, nicael, but I've seen a fair number of his bug reports get upvotes, so I don't think that's it. Not sure though.

Comment: @Nathan well, no doubt that with nicael, many users' finger is way more light on the downvote trigger.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it's funny how nicael's question gets -2 but this gets +6! +1 BTW

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ yeah, no +1 from me but also no -1

Answer (score 5):

Upon doing an inspect element on the recent achievements, it seems like the **fixed** **width** is causing the issue.

```
.topbar .icon-achievements {
    /* width: 36px; */
    background-position: -220px -54px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is the screenshot of **Fixed "width: 36px;"** (as currently set):

> [image]

I commented out the CSS width property (width: 36px) from the class ".topbar .icon-achievements" and it fixes the issue.

The other options here is to set the "width: inherit;" which inherits width that defined by parent. I tried this and it worked too. Upon changing "width" to "inherit" value, now hovering over the link it shows "43.0781px" as the width and *not* "36px".

Now here is how it looks upon setting **"width: inherit;"** (or just **commenting** out):

> [image]

And, we could add a padding for *left* and *right* space to it.

```
.topbar .icon-achievements {
    /* width: 36px; */
    width: inherit;
    background-position: -220px -54px;
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is how it looks now: (notice the padding on left and right side of +7400)

> [image]

And finally, to fix the off-center issue, change the "margin-top:" property value of the ".topbar .icon-achievements .unread-count" class.

```
.topbar .icon-achievements .unread-count {
    .
    .
    margin-top: 10px; /* changed from 9px; */
    .
    .
}
```

There might be another way to achieve this but that's what I can think of at the moment. The values I used for *padding* and *margin-top* properties are for example purpose only. The actual value can be set as per the UI design requirement.

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 44.0.2403.107 (64-bit)